# How to use _ultoa_s and _gcvt_s in Linux (using C++)?

Tags: c++, linux, type-conversion, char

I've tried to convert numbers to string by the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned short a(3);
    float b(233.233);
    char a_string[100];
    char b_string[100];

    _ultoa_s(a,a_string,sizeof(a_string),10);
    _gcvt_s(b_string,sizeof(b_string),b,8);

    cout << a_string << endl;
    cout << b_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is compiled and works well when I use windows but the compilation is failed when I use Linux (I use gcc compiler).
I get the following error message:

```
file_5.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file_5.cpp:12:44: error: ‘_ultoa_s’ was not declared in this scope
     _ultoa_s(a,a_string,sizeof(a_string),10);
                                            ^
file_5.cpp:13:42: error: ‘_gcvt_s’ was not declared in this scope
     _gcvt_s(b_string,sizeof(b_string),b,8);
                                          ^
```

The purpose of this part of code is to convert a number to a string which later I will be able to write to a file or use it as a file name, so if you have another idea how to do it in another way, it can also be helpful.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Who told you about those non-standard functions? What did they tell you about what header files are needed?

Comment: As for a *standard* way to convert a number to a string, see [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). And if your compiler is new enough, also see [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) and [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print). And of course [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Comment: In C++ use std::to_string overloads that return std::string (include <string>). Do not use some kind of platform C API functions and expect those to compile portably.

Comment: I took them from here: https://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-float-to-char-Array-in-CPlusPlus.html

Comment: The lesson for today: Any function beginning with an underscore `_` are *non-standard* and *non-portable*. Try to avoid those.

Comment: Random internet sites give random advice.

Comment: As far as I know both are Microsoft specific *secure* versions of `itoa` and `gcvt`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-s-itow-s?view=msvc-170 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gcvt-s?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are vendor-specific non-portable functions for one particular proprietary operating system. Don't use them.

Instead have a look at the standardised, and therefore portable, [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) from the `<string>` header:

```
    unsigned short const a = 3;
    float const b = 233.233;
    std::string const a_string = std::to_string(a);
    std::string const b_string = std::to_string(b);
```